# Kubectl status nodes provides different responses for equivalent clusters

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, status

I have recently started using kubectl krew (v0.3.4), which later was used to install "status" plugin (v0.4.1).

I am managing right now different clusters, and I'm checking the nodes' status. Most of the clusters answer something **exactly** like:

```
Node/[NodeName], created 25d ago  linux Oracle Linux Server 7.8     
(amd64), kernel 4.1.12-124.36.4.el7uek.x86_64, kubelet v1.18.2, kube-proxy v1.18.2 
cpu: 0.153/7 (2%)     
mem: 4.4GB/7.1GB (63%)    
ephemeral-storage: 2.2GB
```

There is one cluster that answers, for some reason:

```
Node/[nodeName], created 11d ago     
linux Oracle Linux Server 7.8 (amd64), kernel 4.1.12-124.26.5.el7uek.x86_64, kubelet v1.18.2, kube-proxy v1.18.2     
cpu: 5, mem: 7.1GB, ephemeral-storage: 2.2GB
```

(Let me clarify that I'm trying to automate some resources checking and the way resources are differently displayed is quite annoying, plus the used vs total resources is exactly what I need!)

I am absolutely unable to locate the status plugin repo, and I have no idea where to go with this issue. kubectl version says that both clusters have the same server version, I'm executing the kubectl status command from my local in both cases and... I am completely out of ideas.

Does anyone know why this might be happening, or when can I go to look for answers?

Comment: How exactly are you executing the request for node status? From where is this node status being executed? What kind of output do you expect to get when checking for status? If you asking trying to automate the check I would request the status directly from API.

Comment: Well I see that you are trying to get some values from the above information and to hit some kind of autoscaling or metric push to some where. What you can try and check is that if you have run kubectl krew update to update all the existing plugins or check the version of status plugin. Then again I would advise you to use Kubernetes APIs for this purpose as it's more reliable than the krew plugins. This is because in the background that's what is happening. Thanks

Comment: Hey guys! I don't have that much experience with K8s. I am indeed trying to automate some info-gathering, using python+kubernetes client library, which has been useful for lots of things. But I am unable to get the used/total resources using this library or kubernetes API, that's why one colleague suggested status. 
Do you happen to know a more elegant way of getting used vs total resources of the nodes of a cluster?
Thanks

Comment: Kubectl plugin Status repo: https://github.com/bergerx/kubectl-status  
Node status template: https://github.com/bergerx/kubectl-status/blob/0fe3e2e0be75fbb3ea22d4863643660a7c63c7ba/pkg/plugin/templates/templates.tmpl#L541  
Where node metrics come from: https://github.com/bergerx/kubectl-status/blob/0fe3e2e0be75fbb3ea22d4863643660a7c63c7ba/pkg/plugin/plugin.go#L426
You can check it manually: `kubectl proxy &  sleep 3 && curl http://127.0.0.1:8001/apis/metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/nodes && kill %%`

Comment: I guess the output difference caused by the different versions of the status plugin (templates.tmpl, line 327): https://github.com/bergerx/kubectl-status/commit/90cae3e233a87950a75117b3d9ec9e6d0b24110a#diff-ea0b6ae93a1c760fbb2d0c09a20a4b80

Answer (score 0):

To display used and total resources you can use `kubectl top`

> Display Resource (CPU/Memory/Storage) usage.
>
> The top command allows you to see the resource consumption for nodes or pods.
>
> This command requires Metrics Server to be correctly configured and working on the server.
>
> Available Commands:
> node        Display Resource (CPU/Memory/Storage) usage of nodes
> pod         Display Resource (CPU/Memory/Storage) usage of pods
>
> Usage:
> kubectl top [flags] [options]

You can also have a look at [Tools for Monitoring Resources](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/resource-usage-monitoring/) inside Kubernetes docs.

As for doing the same using [Kubernetes Python Client](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python) you can use:

```
from kubernetes.config import load_kube_config                                  
from kubernetes.client import CustomObjectsApi                                  
load_kube_config()                                                              
cust = CustomObjectsApi()                                                       
cust.list_cluster_custom_object('metrics.k8s.io', 'v1beta1', 'nodes') # All node metrics
cust.list_cluster_custom_object('metrics.k8s.io', 'v1beta1', 'pods') # All Pod Metrics
```